# Trying to Insert data into DB with IF statement and foreach loop

Tags: laravel, insertion

This insertion code is for assigning "Subjects to the Class". My controller is ok, web.php is ok, and I have cross-checked my model and database table. But I don't know why this code is not working for insertion. When I remove the IF statement and foreach loop, then it works. Otherwise, it does not show a success message and goes to the next page.

```
public function insert(Request $request)
{
    if (!empty($request->subject_id)) {
        foreach ($request->subject_id as $subject_id) {
            $save = new ClassSubjectModel;
            $save->class_id = $request->class_id;
            $save->subject_id = $subject_id;
            $save->status = $request->status;
            $save->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
            $save->save();
        }

        return view ('admin/assign_subject/list')->with('success', "Subject Successfully Assigned to Class");
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'No subject selected. Please try again.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing `dd($request->subject_id);` before the if. What does it show?

Comment: "*When i remove the IF statement and foreach loop then it works*" - this would suggest `$request->subject_id` is not set, or not an array, right?  So what debugging have you tried?  Have you looked at what your `$request` looks like, eg `dd($request->all());`?  Have you checked your form to make sure it is sending inputs `name`d  `subject_id[]`?

Comment: yes i used dd($request->subject_id); it's showing subject Id's in chrome.

Comment: dd($request->subject_id); when i put this code befoe IF it shows this in Chrome "null // app\Http\Controllers\ClassSubjectController.php:37"

Comment: Your last 2 comments contradict each other.  But they both tell you something is wrong with your $request, which comes from your form.  Start debugging.